# Dialog not send content to the EditText ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a problem.

I have a dialog that has an EditText. The contents of this EditText I caught and put in a ListView, the error is that my variable that receives the contents of the EditText only receives null. 
move contents of dialog for the listview was to be quiet

code:[pastebin.com] [http://pastebin.com/MrNChnPt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
txtNomedaLinha.Text
```

try

```
Item_ListView newItem = new Item_ListView (txtNomedaLinha.getText().toString());
```

There might be more going on there if you have other issues with layout and so on, but try this first and see what happens.

Comment: I used the Debug and this line

  EditText txtNomedaLinha <EditText> = findViewById (Resource.Id.txtNomedaLinha);

the txtNomelinha this to NULL, it was to have my content

Comment: resolved

just went and got my objdialog

EditText txtNomedaLinha = objDialogAddNewLine.FindViewById <EditText> (Resource.Id.txtNomedaLinha);